# How to learn Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning

I want to get into machine learning. I've been in information security for the last 10 years so i have an IT background.

Where is the best place to start:
Can anyone recommend a good book? And also a platform i can use to practice (preferably free)
Also if there are any online courses someone could recommend that would be great.

I looked into AWS's offering of machine learning but that is not included in the free tier.

Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: If you don't know how to code, learn Python. Then learn statistics.

Comment: Searching google will help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Online Course: Andrew Ng, Machine Learning Course from Coursera.
- Book: Tom Mitchell, Machine Learning, McGraw-Hill, 1997.

Answer (score 1):

Courses: Andrew Ng Machine Learning Course from Coursera is what introduced me to machine learning, and I cannot think of a better way to do it. The course focuses on the theory rather than practice, but it offers solid theoretical foundations. [fast.ai](http://www.fast.ai) Machine Learning course is more programming oriented, I haven't taken it but it looks good.

Books: Hands on machine learning with Scikit-learn and Tensorflow by Aurélien Géron has a decent amount of theory explained in a very simple way, and it complements it with lots of code examples. If you want to dig deeper in statistics and theory, The Elements of Statistical Learning might be a good resource.

Practice: [Kaggle](http://www.kaggle.com) is for sure the best place to practice and learn. After reading something or doing some course I advise to download the Titanic dataset and try to submit predictions.

Comment: fast.ai is not at all for complete beginners as they will get lost in the forums.., the course is awesome as I have watched it online completely, It starts from RF all the way to NN, linear regression etc..

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right. The DL ones in fast.ai are quite hardcore.