# Which Data Science book gives complete guideline to data science?

Tags: data-science-model, books

There are many books in the stores on data science. Is there any book that gives complete guideline to data science? Like separately talks about python (not R), statistics, math, data Visualization software etc. Overall, I need to have a book that talks about complete guideline to data science in any field, or important fields like business, commerce etc.

Comment: It's important to realize that **there cannot be a single book which is "complete" about data science**, especially practical aspects such as software libraries and tools. The domain is too vast and evolves too fast: even if this was somehow possible, it would already be incomplete by the time the author is finished writing it. Additionally a data science book which would cover any application in any field would require expertise in literally everything from medicine to astrophysics, it's totally impossible.

Comment: Yes, I can understand. I do not want details about all the topics, I want a full roadmap that mention every topic in very short.

Comment: I'm afraid that even this is not realistic, there might be books which go quickly through many topics but then there wouldn't be enough detail to understand things well (for example would you expect to learn everything about medicine from just one book?). Also be careful that data science is not something which can be learned only from a book, it requires a lot of practice too. If you want to seriously learn it, in my opinion the best way is to follow a proper course.

Comment: I agree with you totally. Can you suggest me a proper course that is not paid( having some financial crisis right now, not gonna lie)?

Comment: I don't have any recommendation myself, maybe you'll find an answer in [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/32438/64377) or [that one](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/14313/64377).

Comment: Ahh got it. I am following the same guideline, so feeling a bit more relaxed.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, there are loads of options.
Two that I would recommend to anyone:

1. [Data Science for Business](https://data-science-for-biz.com/) - Provost & Fawcett - Bigger picture
2. [Data Science From Scratch](https://joelgrus.com/books/) - Joel Grus - Finer details

Comment: Please do explain why you recommend these two.